# Generating all possible combinations with a dynamic size d?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make d here dynamic, i.e., I want to be able to generate all possible combinations of array values without knowing the value of d in advance.

Right now, I'm using if-clause and I can only support d from 1 to 4.

Those are the input parameters: d, max, min, and sz.

```
if( d == 4 )
{
        for( double i = min ; i <= max ; i = i+ sz )
        {
            for( double j = min ; j <= max ; j = j + sz )
            {
                for( double h = min ; h<=max ; h = h + sz )
                {
                    for( double p = min ; p<=max ; p = p + sz )
                    {
                        double[] att = {i, j, h, p};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

if( d == 3 )
{
    for( double i = min ; i <= max ; i = i+ sz )
    {
        for( double j = min ; j <= max ; j = j + sz )
        {
            for( double h = min ; h<=max ; h = h + sz )
            {   
                double[] att = {i, j, h};
            }
        }
    }   
}

if( d == 2 )
{
    for( double i = min ; i <= max ; i = i+ sz )
    {
        for( double j = min ; j <= max ; j = j + sz )
        {
            double[] att = {i, j};
        }
    }   
}

if( d == 1 )
{
    for( double i = min ; i <= max ; i = i+ sz )
    {
        double[] att = {i, j};
    }   
}
```

As you can see, if I don't know the value of d before, I won't be able to do it.

**and one more thing, I don't want to use any template or predefined classes like List, etc.**

Comment: You can do that using a for loop outside of your if statements.

Comment: and what are you returning, an array of that size with random values in it?

Comment: I just wanna print out the array 'att' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is your friend here. The restriction against predefined classes makes the code a bit uglier, but it should function all the same. It's also very bad complexity-wise (you're making a lot of extra objects as you recurse), but if you really want a variable number of nested loops this is the way to go.

```
private static void makeAtt(double min, double max, double sz, int depth, double[] vals){
    //Guard against bad depth
    if (depth < 0) return;
    if (depth == 0){
        System.out.print("{"); 
        for(double d : vals){
            System.out.print(d + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("}\n\n");
    }
    else{
        for(double i = min; i < max; i += sz){
            double[] newVals = new double[vals.length + 1];
            for(int z = 0; z < vals.length; z++) newVals[z] = vals[z];
            newVals[vals.length] = i;
            makeAtt(min, max, sz, depth - 1, newVals);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample running:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  makeAtt(0, 3, 1, 3, new double[0]);
}
```

Output:

{0.0 0.0 0.0 }

{0.0 0.0 1.0 }

{0.0 0.0 2.0 }

{0.0 1.0 0.0 }

{0.0 1.0 1.0 }

{0.0 1.0 2.0 }

{0.0 2.0 0.0 }

{0.0 2.0 1.0 }

{0.0 2.0 2.0 }

{1.0 0.0 0.0 }

{1.0 0.0 1.0 }

{1.0 0.0 2.0 }

{1.0 1.0 0.0 }

{1.0 1.0 1.0 }

{1.0 1.0 2.0 }

{1.0 2.0 0.0 }

{1.0 2.0 1.0 }

{1.0 2.0 2.0 }

{2.0 0.0 0.0 }

{2.0 0.0 1.0 }

{2.0 0.0 2.0 }

{2.0 1.0 0.0 }

{2.0 1.0 1.0 }

{2.0 1.0 2.0 }

{2.0 2.0 0.0 }

{2.0 2.0 1.0 }

{2.0 2.0 2.0 }

---

Something to note though; Both my code and your original answer actually generate all possible *permutations*, not combinations. If you want combinations, you should make each number start at the previous one before incrementing, rather than the min. Thanks to the way the recursion is set up, all you have to do is change the recursive call to:

```
makeAtt(i, max, sz, depth - 1, newVals);
```

Comment: the code is not printing out a correct output. I tried to use depth as d, and initialized vale[] to zeros array, but all I get are arrays with the last element changed.

Comment: vale should be initialized to a length 0 array; the elements are appended on to it. It seemed to work for me, I'll edit my answer with some sample output.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to love this.  I struggled with this myself and devised the following algorithm after several hours of headaches:

```
// nCr
public static long c(int n, int r) {
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
        result *= n - (r - i);
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}

public static int[] getCombo(int n, int r, long k) {
    int[] result = new int[r];
    int cur = 1;
    long sum = 0;
    while (r > 0) {
        long tot = c(n - cur, r - 1);
        if (sum + tot <= k) {
            sum += tot;
            cur += 1;
        } else {
            result[result.length - r] = cur;
            cur += 1;
            r--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < c(10,3); i++) {
        int[] res = getCombo(10, 3, i);
        System.out.print(i + " : ");
        for (int j : res) System.out.print(j+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

To use this, simply specify the number of elements (n) and how many out of that you want to pick (r), and which combination you want (k), starting at 0.  This allows you to iterate over the combinations without holding them all in an array.

For example, getCombo(10, 3, 0) will give you [1, 2, 3].  Of course selecting 3 from 10 has 120 possibilities, so  getCombo(10, 3, 119) will give you [8,9,10]

The algorithm is based on calculating the various of combinations of numbers that start with a 1 and then a 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My code is very similar to @Mshnik's, but without the copying, question is if you can process the combination in one place or have to return all combinations at  once...

http://ideone.com/uCUVfk

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Combinations
{

    static void printCombinations( int K, int[] A ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i ) {
            printCombinations( K, A, i, new int[K], 0 );
        }
    }

    static void printCombinations( int K, int[] A, int from, int[] curr,  int idx ) {
        if ( from >= A.length ) return;
        if ( idx == K ) { System.out.println( Arrays.toString(curr) ); return; }
        curr[idx] = A[from];
        for ( int i = from + 1; i < A.length; ++i ) {
            printCombinations( K, A, i, curr,  idx + 1 );
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        // K - elements in combination
        int K = Integer.parseInt( br.readLine() );
        // N - input array size
        int N = Integer.parseInt( br.readLine() );
        StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer( br.readLine() );
        int[] A = new int[N];
        for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
            A[i] = Integer.parseInt( tok.nextToken() );
        }
        //System.out.println( "DEBUG: " + Arrays.toString( A ) );
        printCombinations( K, A );
    }
}
```

place where complete combination is available is

```
if ( idx == K ) { System.out.println( Arrays.toString(curr) ); return; }
```

I'm just printing it, you can pass it to some method and process it...